# Shutter count from NEF photo

Tags: photos, preview, camera, metadata, exif

I know Nikon embeds the shutter count in the EXIF of their NEF raw files.

What's the easiest way to find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open the photo in Preview, press Command-I (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to bring up the Inspector. Click the circled i (`ⓘ`) tab, and then the `Exif` tab. At the bottom of the list you'll find `Image Number`.

***This is your camera's shutter count.***

[image]